# FPgrowth computing association in pyspark vs scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

***Using*** :

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html

**Python Code:**

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
model = FPGrowth.train(dataframe,0.01,10)
```

**Scala:**

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt")

val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))

val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.2)
  .setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)

model.freqItemsets.collect().foreach { itemset =>
  println(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") + ", " + itemset.freq)
}

val minConfidence = 0.8
model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence).collect().foreach { rule =>
  println(
    rule.antecedent.mkString("[", ",", "]")
      + " => " + rule.consequent .mkString("[", ",", "]")
      + ", " + rule.confidence)
}
```

From code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/api/python/PythonMLLibAPI.scala) it shows that scala part doesn't have minimum confidence.

```
def trainFPGrowthModel(
      data: JavaRDD[java.lang.Iterable[Any]],
      minSupport: Double,
      numPartitions: Int): FPGrowthModel[Any] = {
    val fpg = new FPGrowth()
      .setMinSupport(minSupport)
      .setNumPartitions(numPartitions)

    val model = fpg.run(data.rdd.map(_.asScala.toArray))
    new FPGrowthModelWrapper(model)
  }
```

How to add minConfidence to generate association rule in case of pyspark? We can see that scala has the example but python does not have the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.2**

There is a `DataFrame` base `ml` API which provides `AssociationRules`:

```py
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth

data = ...

fpm = FPGrowth(minSupport=0.3, minConfidence=0.9).fit(data)
associationRules = fpm.associationRules.
```

**Spark < 2.2**

As for now PySpark doesn't support extracting association rules (`DataFrame` based `FPGrowth` API with Python support is a work in progress [SPARK-1450](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14501)) but we can easily address that.

First you'll have to install SBT (just go [the downloads page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html)) and follow the instructions for your operating system.

Next you'll have to create a simple Scala project with only two files:

```
.
├── AssociationRulesExtractor.scala
└── build.sbt
```

You can adjust it later to follow [the established directory structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html).

Next add following to the `build.sbt` (adjust Scala version and Spark version to match the one you use):

```scala
name := "fpm"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

val sparkVersion = "1.6.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion
)
```

and following to the `AssociationRulesExtractor.scala`:

```scala
package com.example.fpm

import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules.Rule
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object AssociationRulesExtractor {
  def apply(rdd: RDD[Rule[String]]) = {
    rdd.map(rule => Array(
      rule.confidence, rule.javaAntecedent, rule.javaConsequent
    ))
  }
}
```

Open terminal emulator of your choice, go to the root directory of the project and call:

```
sbt package
```

It will generate a jar file in the target directory. For example in Scala 2.10 it will be:

```
target/scala-2.10/fpm_2.10-1.0.jar
```

Start PySpark shell or use `spark-submit` and pass path to the generated jar file as to `--driver-class-path`:

```
bin/pyspark --driver-class-path /path/to/fpm_2.10-1.0.jar
```

In non-local mode:

```
bin/pyspark --driver-class-path /path/to/fpm_2.10-1.0.jar --jars /path/to/fpm_2.10-1.0.jar
```

In cluster mode jar should be present on all nodes.

Add some convenience wrappers:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowthModel
from pyspark.mllib.common import _java2py
from collections import namedtuple


rule = namedtuple("Rule", ["confidence", "antecedent", "consequent"])

def generateAssociationRules(model, minConfidence):
    # Get active context
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

    # Retrieve extractor object
    extractor = sc._gateway.jvm.com.example.fpm.AssociationRulesExtractor

    # Compute rules
    java_rules = model._java_model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence)

    # Convert rules to Python RDD
    return _java2py(sc, extractor.apply(java_rules)).map(lambda x:rule(*x))
```

Finally you can use these helpers as a function:

```
generateAssociationRules(model, 0.9)
```

or as a method:

```py
FPGrowthModel.generateAssociationRules = generateAssociationRules
model.generateAssociationRules(0.9)
```

This solution depends on internal PySpark methods so it is not guaranteed that it will be portable between versions.

Comment: You can generate and get association rules in PySpark using Spark <2.2 with a little bit of py4j code, I'll put the code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate and get association rules in PySpark using Spark <2.2 with a little bit of py4j code:

```
# model was produced by FPGrowth.train() method
rules = sorted(model._java_model.generateAssociationRules(0.9).collect(), 
    key=lambda x: x.confidence(), reverse=True)
for rule in rules[:200]:
    # rule variable has confidence(), consequent() and antecedent() 
    # methods for individual value access.
    print rule
```