# Association rules in Spark using Python

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, recommendation-engine

I'm investigating the possibility to use association rules through Spark in Python. Sadly, according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html#association-rules), this is only implemented in Java and Scala right now. I've done some thoughtfully investigation to see if there is any similar implementation, and what I've found so far is the apriori algorithm. I think I will dive into using that instead, but I'm curious to hear if anyone has or knows if association rules will be implemented for a Spark application? This since Spark is awesome and it fits my project (building a recommendation engine handling billions of rows).

A similar topic is discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107643/fpgrowth-computing-association-in-pyspark-vs-scala), but it doesn't seem to be qualified as working or not. I also want to check if there is a better solution that actually is a real Python implementation.

Cheers!